# Is there a way to embed dbt docs within Confluence?

Tags: dbt, confluence

dbt's built in docs is amazing for tracking data lineage, data dictionaries, business rules etc. But publishing these docs to a central place in a secure way without using dbt Cloud is proving to be not as straight forward.

Like a lot of businesses we use Confluence for project tracking and documentation. It would be beneficial to have all documentation centralised in one place for both technical and business users. Has anyone embeded dbt docs within Confluence before? Are there any existing plug-ins for this?

The nirvana state would be to have some CI which automatically keeps the embeded dbt docs up to date, but baby steps.

I found this on the Confluence support page which talks about using Confluence to serve static content:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/how-to-use-confluence-to-serve-static-content-677282407.html

But I'd prefer to not muck around with backend Confluence server things. It's a bit outside of my area of expertise.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps someone else get to a better answer but the simple answer is "not easily."

Example with just straight netlify + password protection is well documented here by peter_hanssens:
[Publishing dbt Docs to Netlify](https://discourse.getdbt.com/t/publishing-dbt-docs-to-netlify/121)

But if you want something much more robust, I'd highly recommend following this deploy CI/CD pipeline that automatically loads the updated docs after changes as well as uses AWS cognito for user management:
[How to host dbt Docs](https://www.entechlog.com/blog/data/how-to-host-dbt-docs/)

Aside from that, my thinking would be something like:

- start with the [outputs](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/commands/cmd-docs) of the `dbt docs generate` command (`index.html` + `catalog.json`)
- "unfold" that into a directory of individual html pages
- hit the atlassian api to create new pages for each of the docs pages
- create the content of the new confluence pages as links to each docs page within your bitbucket repo so that it will do the interactive loading illustrated here in [this atlassian community answer](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Confluence-questions/insert-bitbucket-content-directly-into-confluence-document/qaq-p/1316916)
- profit?